# Remove additional query string from 404 redirect

Tags: asp.net, query-string, sitecore

I need to remove the query string from url when the page is redirected to custom 404 error page when request to a non-existing resource, e.g

`www.ourweb/non-exsiting.aspx` will be redirected to

`www.ourweb/errors/notfound.aspx?item=%2fpayments%2faccount%2fnon-existing&user=extranet\Anonymous&site=website_121_payments`

I need to remove all the query string from this url.

What is the best way to do it?

What I did was created a inherited class from `sitecore.pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest` as

```
public class ItemNotFoundProcessor : ExecuteRequest    
{    
      protected override void RedirectOnItemNotFound(string url) 
      { 
         url = Settings.ItemNotFoundUrl; 
         base.RedirectOnItemNotFound(url); 
      } 
}
```

And added this class in the `site.config`

```
processor type ="namespace.ItemNotFoundProcessor" 
processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel"
```

It seems to be working, but not sure if there is any side effect of it.

Could anybody please let me know whether this is appropriate solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those querystring parameters are just there in case you want to use them while rendering the NotFound page. So it's no problem to omit them. Using an override of the ExecuteRequest processor for this also seems appropiate. So you're good here.

Comment: Thanks, the main concerns is about security, don't really think it is a good idea to expose the user name in the url.

Comment: You may also want to consider this: http://www.herskind.co.uk/blog/2012/03/sitecore-404-without-302

Comment: @jammykam Why wouldn't you put your comment (reference to rewrite parameter) as an answer?